# adding rating system to detailviewcontroller

Tags: iphone

hello does anyone know a rating system that can be implemented for iphone detail view that allows user to rate the services offered.
ive used touchcustoms however i cant figure out how to implement it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

searching for "Ratingview" google gave me this:

http://code.google.com/p/agautam-code/source/browse/trunk/iPhone/?r=7#iPhone/RatingView

looks quite nice

Comment: great thanks so much it really helped me out :)
one small question i have on a sidenote to this project
how would i make it remember the old rating generated by the user.
here is the code that loads on startup
[starView displayRating:1.5]; 

however i want it to be changed according to this 
-(void)ratingChanged:(float)newRating {
    ratingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rating is: %1.1f", newRating];
can anyone show me how to do this please

Comment: @Alex: I am not very sure, what u mean. Is it about saving persistently or to use the same variable for the old and new value?
  
case 1: See NSUserdefaults and CoreData
  
case 2: just write it on a member variable in ur viewcontroller